# The size of character changed in fbox

Tags: spacing, symbols, fbox

The source is as in the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{ctexart}

\begin{document}
\noindent
【

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\noindent
\fbox{【}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like

[image]

As you can see, the widths of the same character are different.

I'm using texlive 2018.48691-6 and the file is compiled with the following command

```
xelatex main.tex
```

Comment: If you compare `x【x` and `\fbox{x【x}` you see the width is the same. It looks to me that there is some correction done at the begin of the line, maybe some microtype feature etc.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Yes, you are correct.

Comment: If I compile with `\documentclass[a4paper,fontset=windows,UTF8]{ctexart}`, I get a space preceding the character in both cases. And also if I do `\fbox{\hbox{【}}`. Without the `UTF8` option I get errors.

Comment: As far as I can see, the space is added on purpose, in order to make the symbol the same width as other Chinese characters.

Answer (score 2):

Can't tell you why this is the case but I figured out that enclosing it into a `\mbox` first fixes this issue.

```
% xelatax
\documentclass[a4paper]{ctexart}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent
【

\noindent
\fbox{\mbox{【}}%

\noindent
\fbox{【}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Just adding a low-level `\hbox{..}` is also enough. Seems to me that the way `\fbox` boxes its content does something wrong here. If you use the `adjustbox` package with `\adjustbox{frame}{【}` then it works fine as well.